# Ignore property with attribute in custom JSON converter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

We are using `.NET Core 3.1`. We have a custom JSON converter for `DateTime` and `DateTime?` properties.

**JsonDateTimeConverter.cs**

```cs
public class JsonDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // I want to return false for object properties which have attribute "TimeZoneIgnore"
        
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime) || objectType == typeof(DateTime?);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // convert datetime to timezone
        DateTime? dateTime = (value as DateTime?).ConvertToTimeZone("CEST");

        writer.WriteValue(dateTime);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

**TimeZoneIgnore.cs**

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class TimeZoneIgnore : Attribute { }
```

**Bank.cs**

```cs
public class Bank
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ConvertThis { get; set; }
    [TimeZoneIgnore]
    public DateTime DontConvertThis { get; set; }
}
```

**TestController.cs**

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test123()
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.Converters.Add(new JsonDateTimeConverter());
    
    return Json(new Bank()
    {
        Name = "Test bank",
        ConvertThis = new DateTime(2020, 8, 18, 15, 7, 1),
        DontConvertThis = new DateTime(2020, 8, 18, 15, 7, 1)
    }, settings);
}
```

How can I return `false` in `CanConvert(Type objectType)` for object properties with `TimeZoneIgnore` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JsonConverter` doesn't have the context to determine which property it is being applied to, so there is not an easy way to get the attributes from within it.  On the other hand, a `ContractResolver` does have the context information, because it is responsible for mapping JSON properties to class properties.  It turns out you can also use a `ContractResolver` to programmatically apply or remove `JsonConverters`.

So, instead of applying your `JsonDateTimeConverter` globally in settings, you can use a custom `ContractResolver` to apply it conditionally based on the presence or absence of the `[TimeZoneIgnore]` attribute.  Here is the code you would need for the resolver:

```
public class ConditionalDateTimeResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    static readonly JsonConverter DateTimeConverter = new JsonDateTimeConverter();

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (DateTimeConverter.CanConvert(prop.PropertyType) && 
            !prop.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(TimeZoneIgnore), true).Any())
        {
            prop.Converter = DateTimeConverter;
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

To use the resolver, add it to the `JsonSerializerSettings` instead of adding your converter:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new ConditionalDateTimeResolver();
// settings.Converters.Add(new JsonDateTimeConverter());          <-- remove this line
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8LBZ4S

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.